# Determining disk size for an AKS cluster of 10 nodes

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I have some 30 Microservices which are all stateless. All these app write data to a data store and don't store any state.
I have an AKS cluster which hosts these app . The machines I've chosen is an E series with 32 Ram and 8 cores and 100gb HD. This seems to be a good enough and machines have a load of 25-50% avg

In all of this do i really need a hard disk at all and if I do then for what reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, you don't need a hard disk. Check the AKS disk monitoring.

Before updating the cluster, make sure none of your PVs are local. My advice would be to restrict permissions on PV creation if this is not already the case.

Comment: i'm sorry but what's a PV

Comment: Persistent volume https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/

This is where you specify the type of storage (local, Azure File Share, Azure disk, etc.).